# ajax request with user input trouble with variable definition

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've built a simple html input so that users can input a zip code and then I have a variable in javascript set to that input. I can console.log this to prove the variable is set and that it is a string. I then try to run an ajax call and sub in the zip but it doesn't work. I can console.log the variable at any stage and see the variable has been updated, but somehow it's a hoisting issue or something where the ajax call value 'userInputZip' always reads to what I initially set. The ajax call works when 'userInputZip' is initially set to a valid zipoAny help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});//end of document.ready

var inputDate = '2015-12-04T20:00:00';
var inputZipCode = '60618';
var userInputZip;

function runAjax(){
console.log(userInputZip);
$.ajax(getJambaseData);
}

// var dataArr = [];

var getJambaseData = {
  type: 'get',
  url:
  'http://api.jambase.com/events?zipCode='+userInputZip+'&api_key=[inserted my key here]',

  // 'http://api.jambase.com/events?zipCode='+userInputZip+'&api_key=[inserted my key here]',
  success: function (data){
    for (i=0; i< 10; i++){
      if(data.Events[i].Date == inputDate){
      var shortDate = data.Events[i].Date.substring(0,10);
      var shortTime = data.Events[i].Date.substring(11,19);
      // dataArr.push(data.Events[i].Date, data.Events[i].Artists[0].Name);
      $("#divID").append('</p>' + 'date::: '+ shortDate + ' time:::' + shortTime + ' show::: ' + data.Events[i].Artists[0].Name + ' time::: ' + data.Events[i].Date + ' address::: ' + data.Events[i].Venue.Address + ' city::: ' + data.Events[i].Venue.City + '</p>');
    }
  }
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log('failed');
  },

}

function findShows(){
  var userZip = document.getElementById("userInput");
  userInputZip = userZip.value;
  document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML = userInputZip;
  runAjax();
}
////////////////////
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mentioned

> but somehow it's a hoisting issue or something where the ajax call value 'userInputZip' always reads to what I initially set

You define `getJambaseData` as a variable when the script is initially executed. You set the url value to `url:
  'http://api.jambase.com/events?zipCode='+userInputZip+'&api_key=[inserted my key here]'`. What else did you expect to happen?

That's like saying `var x = 10;` and expecting it to magically change when you call a function.

What you have to do is move the whole `var getJambaseData = {...}` initialization into `runAjax` function and it should fix it. Or you could skip the variable initialization part and just pass the part inside `{...}` (including the curly braces obviously) inside the `$.ajax` call instead of variable. If you look at jQuery docs you'll see that in most examples and it's the usual syntax.

---

Not related to your question, but here are some friendly words of advice:

- Don't use variable before you define it (reading top to bottom), it will save you a lot of headaches.
- Another recommendation is don't use so much global variables, you could get the `userInputZip` inside `findShows` function and pass it to `runAjax` as function argument. If you'll develop applications in a way where you rely on global state a lot, you'll have a bad time very soon.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I assumed $.ajax called the variable somehow, seeing as how I could choose to place this inside the window.onload and run immediately, or run later in a function. Because of this I thought the ajax call would use the current state of userInputZip. Clearly that is wrong.

Comment: Is it better to just lose the `var`, and place the object contents from there directly into the jQuery Ajax call?  (oops. best is to not use the global variable at all... )

Comment: @KM617 yes, unfortunately things don't work this way. The string is evaluated when you first define it and the `getJambaseData` variable value is set and don't change. Better practice is to define the object when you really need it or as @zipzit recommended, skip the defining variable part and put only the things inside curly braces in `$.ajax` call instead of variable.

Comment: @zipzit Thanks for the recommendation, I'll edit the answer. Initially, I was just looking for the "least changes to make it work" solution.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak... kudos to you for your description of not using the global variable at all. When is the time to start using best practices in coding?  RIGHT NOW!

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much guys, I appreciate the help and clarification. Shed some light on mistakes I hopefully wont make again.